# Ford Focus lost chip key

Tags: ford, focus, smartkey

I lost my key to my Ford Focus but only the chip key I still have a copy that unlocks it and gives my dash power just no ignition 
Can a locksmith make an ignition chip key?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What year is your Focus?

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely that anyone other than a Ford dealer can provide a chipped key that'll start the car. You may have to prove that you're the owner of the vehicle before they'll help with this.

A subsequent comment says that some Ford Focus cars can be reprogrammed using PC software without dealer input. The OP will have to start talking to locksmiths or independent repair shops and/or a Ford dealer to address this issue.

Comment: Actually for Focus MK2 (I don't know if for others as well) it is possible to program keys via Forscan software. I did this for my Focus. Bought used, original key and let locksmith duplicate my original one (just the metal part, sorry, I have no idea how it's called). Using diagnostics cable I then erased all keys from my car and programmed my original one and new one.

Comment: Thanks, @Mark. We don't know if the OP has a MK2. I suspect she'll have to get help for this issue and start talking to locksmiths to see. I've amended my answer.